# Principle of Mathematical Induction Problem with Mathematical Series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me with this problem? Been strugling with it for a few hours now. My finite induction principle is quite rusty.

Consider $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.

1. For $P(n):9+13+...+(4n+5)=\frac{4n^2+14n+1}{2}$, show that $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)$ is true $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.
2. Does the procedure in 1. demonstrate that the proposition is true for every $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$? Justify your answer.
3. Determine the subset of $\mathbb{N}^{*}$ that satisfies the proposition $P(n)$. Justify your answer.

Thank you guys.

Comment: For 1: Assume it works for some $k$. Plug in $k+1$ instead. Check if it still works. For 2: No, but only one test case (here that's $1$) is needed to imply the next case, and the next, and the next, ...all the way to $\infty$. For 3: If it's true for the least case, and it being true for a case implies it being true for the next case, then it must be true for all the cases.

Comment: Can you apply Gauß formula to show the statement is false?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

**#1,2** In essence you can think of this as dominos falling, $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k+1)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ means the dominos are all lined up so that if you tip one, the rest thereafter will fall... you just need one to go. But none will ever go because $P(k)$ is false for all $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

$n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ so we start $n$ at $1$ not $0$.

*Check:*

Let $n=1$, then

$P(1) = 9 \not= \frac{4+14+1}{2} = \frac{19}{2}$, False.

$P(k)$ is not true $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ because $4n^2 +14n+1 \equiv 1 \pmod2$

However if you start with $P(k) = 9 + \cdots +(4k+5) = \frac{4k^2+14k+1}{2}$ true, then $$P(k+1)= \frac{4(k+1)^2+14(k+1)+1}{2} = \frac{4k^2+14k+1}{2} + 4k+9 $$
$$= \frac{4k^2+14k+1}{2} + 4(k+1)+5 = P(k)+4(k+1)+5$$ therefore $P(k+1)$ would be true by the definition of $P$.

Therefore
the induction step is true: *if* $P(k)$, then $P(k+1)$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, however the statement is always false because we can never satisfy the *if*, so I think the goal of this exercise was to show you the importance  of testing a base case, finding at least one tipping of a domino.

---

**#3**
The subset of $\mathbb{N}^*$ which satisfies $P(n)$ is the empty subset $\varnothing$ because as mentioned above $2 \not|\;\;4n^2 + 14n+1 $ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, so $9+ \cdots + (4k+5)$ is always an integer on the LHS while $\frac{4n^2+14n+1}{2} = 2n^2+7n+\frac{1}{2}$ is never an integer on the RHS, so they can never be equal.